# Changing the size of a div with a class?

Tags: css, html

I have this div in my code:

```
<div id="advice" class="validation-advice" style="">some text here</div>
```

Now, can I use a selector or something to say that all divs with the class *validation-advice* should only have a width of lets say 100px?

I tried:

```
div.validation-advice{
   width:100px;
}
```

Strange thing is, the div width changes (I used Firebug to see) but the text inside the div does not wrap when the div ends. Whats missing?

Thanks!

Comment: This is very basic stuff, which you can find everywhere on the internet..

Comment: Yes you can. Or is that not the answer your looking for. Be more specific.

Comment: I added some more information to my post

Comment: Show the html of one div with text that doesn't wrap at the ends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div.validation-advice{
  width:100px;
}
```

The problem that your text not wraps at the end of the div is because you just enter plain text. If you do it like this you have no problems:

```
<div class="validation-advice">
  <p>Your text here</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a piece of cake!

```
.validation-advice {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thats strange, I added the class and the div really changes the size, I debugged to see it. But the text inside the div still doesnt wrap when the div ends. Do I need some more css? I want to control the text wrapping by using the width.

Comment: This would also effect non-div's

Answer (score 0):

probably your divs have display:inline, try this:

```
div.validation-advice{
  display: block;
  width:100px;
}
```